# Values for an attribute not assigned to the right variable

Tags: class, dictionary, attributes, python-3.6

Sorry for the vague title I wasn't quite sure how to word it:

Let's say we have a class and it contains dictionaries embedded in a larger dictionary.

```
class AnObject(object):

    grail = {'Grail' : '', 'Quest' : ''}
    spam = {'More spam' : '', 'Less spam' : ''}
    parrot = {'More parrot' : '', 'Less parrot' : '', 'Grail' : grail}
    egg = {'Spam' : spam, 'Parrot' : parrot }
```

Then we want to call these attributes by other names

```
self.egg = egg
self.parrot = egg['Parrot']
self.moreparrot = self.parrot['More parrot']
```

This will bring up the right locations but for some reason I'm finding...

```
>>>knight = AnObject()
>>>knight.moreparrot = x
>>>knight.moreparrot
x
>>>knight.egg
{'Parrot' : {'More parrot' : '', 'Less parrot' : ''}...}
```

But this works fine:

```
>>>knight.egg['Parrot']['More parrot'] = x
>>>knight.egg['Parrot']['More parrot']
x
>>>knight.egg
{'Parrot' : {'More parrot' : '', 'Less parrot' : ''}...}
```

These should point to the same variable, but I am getting different results. How come?

Edit:

This might be totally accidental but for some reason Spam is consistent.

```
self.egg = egg
self.spam = egg['Spam']
self.morespam = self.spam['More spam']

>>>knight = AnObject()
>>>knight.morespam = x
>>>knight.morespam
x
>>>knight.egg['Spam']['More spam']
x
>>>knight.egg
{'Spam' : {'More spam' : 'x', 'Less spam' : ''}...}
```

Comment: Not sure if I want to use this as a dupe, but it's essentially the same issue: [Why can a function modify some arguments as perceived by the caller, but not others?](//stackoverflow.com/q/575196). Basically, the difference is that `knight.moreparrot = x` reassigns a new value to a variable, but `knight.egg['Parrot']['More parrot'] = x` modifies a dictionary. Those are two completely different operations.

Comment: This is going to make it more confusing, but for some reason that operation works when I use spam instead of parrot.